# Possible to configure my VPS as a proxy of mail sent by another mail server?

Tags: proxy, nas, smtp, mail-server, email-server

I have a NAS which deployed with a full-featured mail server, but I cannot send mail to most of the other mailboxes because its IP is always blocked from sending mail, and the mail sent will be returned. Meanwhile, my VPS can do it. Is there any possibility to make my VPS a proxy for my NAS's mail server?

The NAS itself is only exposed to the Internet by a reverse proxy on the VPS. All IMAP, POP3, and SMTP ports of VPS were configured to forward all traffic. If all goes as expected, my NAS will send mail to my VPS, and the VPS will then send mail to the target mail server, such as outlook.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "full featured mail server."  An "email system" consists of various parts - where the outbound and inbound service is provided by smtp.  Smtp doesn't handle user mailbox features, as there are separate protocols for that like pop and imap.  So yes, you should be able to set your vps's smtp server (typically sendmail, postfix, exim, courier etc.) to forward mail to whatever is running on your NAS, and also to relay sent mail from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to host a SMTP relay on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1706930/possible-to-host-a-smtp-relay-on-linux)

Comment: Im voting to close this as a duplucate of your other question https://superuser.com/questions/1706930/possible-to-host-a-smtp-relay-on-linux

Comment: Unfortunately, the previous question didn't really provide a solution but corrected a misunderstanding. I am still looking for a solution. Since I don't know how SMTP protocol works, I am trying to make iptables to capture all outbound traffic on SMTP ports, while using kcptun to create a tunnel, so that it might work similarly to using a VPN.